# How to Enrich a Custom Extraction Model with Multiple Datasets

Tags: azure, azure-form-recognizer, azure-ai

Suppose I have a dataset (let's call it Dataset1) consisting of 100 documents, and I'd like to create a custom feature extraction model. After tagging specific features within these documents, I train and generate a model named 'model1'. Due to the sensitive nature of the data (medical information), I am required to delete these files afterward.

However, I want to enrich 'model1' with another dataset (let's call it Dataset2), which also consists of 100 documents with different features. How can I achieve this? Do I need to create a separate model (model2) from Dataset2 and then combine 'model1' and 'model2' into a new model named 'model3'? Additionally, how many times can I perform this type of model composition without losing the integrity or performance of the original model?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use the [compose](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/ai-services/document-intelligence/how-to-guides/compose-custom-models?view=doc-intel-4.0.0&tabs=studio#create-a-composed-model) model approach to utilize your custom models to generate a single model.

As for the limit, you can assign up to 100 trained custom models to a single model ID.

Regarding performance, whenever you submit a document for analysis, it classifies the form, chooses the best-matching assigned model, and returns results.

For more information, refer to the compose custom models [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/ai-services/document-intelligence/concept-composed-models?view=doc-intel-4.0.0).

In your case, for multiple datasets, create custom models and compose them.